# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5

Tags: android

I tried as many solutions as available, but problem could not resolved 
[image]

Comment: if you don't want to use constraint layout then just remove that line from your app build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

Please fix that you have installed Constraintlayout under support repository 
[image: Adndorid Sdk Tool]